# Equivalent for $e^{-x}+e^{-2x}$ when x goes to $+\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, asymptotics

> Find the equivalent for $e^{-x}+e^{-2x}$ when x goes to $+\infty$

My attempts:

$$e^{-x}+e^{-2x}=\underbrace{e^{-2x}}_{\to 0}\left(1+e^{x} \right)\sim_{+\infty}\left(1+e^{x} \right)$$

Thus, $$ e^{-x}+e^{-2x}\sim_{+\infty}\left(1+e^{x} \right)$$

Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right. $1+e^x$ does to $\infty$ for $x\to \infty$.

Comment: No: the l.h.s. tends to $0$ and the r.h.s. to $+\infty$.

Comment: With $t=e^{-x}$, you have $t+t^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $\;\mathrm e^{-2x}=_\infty o(\mathrm e^{-x})$, so
$$\mathrm e^{-x}+\mathrm e^{-2x}\sim_\infty \mathrm e^{-x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-x}+e^{-2x}=e^{-x}(1+e^{-x}) $$

$$=e^{-x}(1+\epsilon (x) )$$

with $\lim_{+\infty}\epsilon (x)=0.$

thus,

$$e^{-x}+e^{-2x}\sim e^{-x}\;\;(x\to+\infty) $$